# JavaFX does not work with IntelliJ (jdk 9)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx-8

JavaFX is not working for me using IntelliJ. While it does compile, I get an Exception when trying to launch. I've found similar issues here, none of which seemed to hold an answer to my problem. The Exception I get is the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:945)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: <init>
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:267)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:255)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:154)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:731)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:418)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:372)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: <init>
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:2614)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2499)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:812)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1821)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:114)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:39)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.Application.loadNativeLibrary(Application.java:112)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.Application.loadNativeLibrary(Application.java:120)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$static$2(GtkApplication.java:109)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.<clinit>(GtkApplication.java:108)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkPlatformFactory.createApplication(GtkPlatformFactory.java:41)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:146)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:257)
    ... 10 more
```

The code required to cause this Exception is only the following:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {

    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        Application.launch(Test.class, args);
    }
}
```

Furthermore, running code form old Eclipse projects using Eclipse is working. However, if I copy the code over to IntelliJ, I get the same Exception.
I do use the java 9 jdk in the project settings.

Comment: Works fine on my machine. What IDE version do you use?

Comment: @y.bedrov Pastebin link because StackOverflow appearently doesn't support multiline in replies: https://pastebin.com/qTkUV6cy

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your Main to:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    launch(args);
}
```

Otherwise your problem might be related to [How to start a new JavaFX project with JDK 9 in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39458945/how-to-start-a-new-javafx-project-with-jdk-9-in-intellij)

Comment: Changing the main makes no difference.

I think the linked thread might be related to the fact that jdk 9 was not yet released at this date. In do have java 9 selected for the Project language level.

Inerestingly enough, it does work if I set both the Project SDK and the Project Language Level to java 8.

Other projects that do not involve JavaFX do work properly using Java 9, though.