# InvocationTargetException with javafx launch

Tags: javafx

I have some trouble with launching a javafx application. To explain, I wrote a code that worked but I was on Ubuntu 19.04 and I decided to reinstall my Linux version (20.04). I copied my code and reinstalled e(fx)clipse, scenebuilder, openjfx, and imported the same jfxrt.jar but nothing worked. I can't manage to launch javafx application, even if the code is empty (ig code). Oh and I have to use java 8 for this homework.

Can you help me please?

Here is my code

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LaunchApplication extends Application {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    //Empty but still error
    @Override
    public void start(Stage arg0) throws Exception {
        
    }

    //Old code, doesnt work anymore
//  @Override
//  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
//      try {
//
//          FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
//          loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("view/Login.fxml"));
//          Parent root = loader.load();
//          
//          Scene scene = new Scene(root);
//          primaryStage.setScene(scene);
//          primaryStage.setResizable(true);
//          primaryStage.show();
//
//      } catch (Exception e) {
//          System.out.println(e);
//      }
//
//  }
}
```

And there my error when running it

````
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: <init>
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:288)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:211)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:675)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:337)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: <init>
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1934)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1817)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:810)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1088)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:107)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:39)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$new$5(GtkApplication.java:156)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.<init>(GtkApplication.java:140)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkPlatformFactory.createApplication(GtkPlatformFactory.java:41)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:146)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:278)
    ... 9 more
    ```
````

Comment: What version of `Java` is installed on your machine?

Comment: Read the comments from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51113343/javafx-does-not-work-with-intellij-jdk-9) to see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: I have java-8-openjdk-amd64 and I set the same version for java compiler and build path. In my build path I have an external jar jfxrt.jar because my java JRE doesn't provide this jar

Comment: It didn't solve :/ Plus, I am on Eclipse